# Matching a dataset on some but not all variables, excepting a deviation of 10% (R)

Tags: r, matching, data-wrangling

To preprocess data for a regression analysis, I want to match it on some variables. For an R beginner like me, the online explanations on how to do this are not a hundred percent clear, so I decided to ask the community here for help.

I want to create a new dataset matched on the variables "size,", "population,", and "IMR". The variable "treated" identifies the treatment group. My data is a panel dataset, with "fid" being the unit-id and "year" as the time variable. All the variables I want to match are continuous, and I would accept a deviation of 10% on the matched variables.

Here is a subset of my data. Thank you in advance:

````
structure(list(fid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L
), treated = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), input = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 
14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L), outcome = c(1L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Population = c(214959.51545763, 
214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 
214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 
214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 
214959.51545763, 214959.51545763, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 
188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 
188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 
188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 188351.766471863, 
188351.766471863, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 
141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 
141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 
141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 141311.181366891, 
140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 
140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 
140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 
140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 140766.772611022, 287479.077991486, 
287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 
287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 
287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 
287479.077991486, 287479.077991486, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 
46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 
46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 
46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 46714.4086914062, 
46714.4086914062, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 
190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 
190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 
190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 190364.178184509, 
144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 
144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 
144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 
144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 144951.521541595, 109964.518005788, 
109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 
109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 
109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 
109964.518005788, 109964.518005788, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 
151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 
151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 
151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 151256.307518005, 
151256.307518005, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 
162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 
162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 
162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 162096.348495483, 
103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 
103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 
103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 
103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 103203.250408173, 456142.28871119, 
456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 
456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 
456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 
456142.28871119, 456142.28871119, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 
170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 
170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 
170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 170299.376556396, 
170299.376556396, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 
51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 
51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 
51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 51209.4864530563, 
79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 
79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 
79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 
79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 79556.1234817505, 116170.138785275, 
116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 
116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 
116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 
116170.138785275, 116170.138785275, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 
218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 
218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 
218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 218341.117115021, 
218341.117115021, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 
167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 
167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 
167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 167641.157600403, 
189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 
189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 
189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 
189979.203140259, 189979.203140259, 189979.203140259), Size = c(343717373304.508, 
343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 
343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 
343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 
343717373304.508, 343717373304.508, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 
119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 
119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 
119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 119544234065.781, 
119544234065.781, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 
160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 
160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 
160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 160415571859.129, 
202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 
202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 
202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 
202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 202139893025.645, 243904979982.436, 
243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 
243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 
243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 
243904979982.436, 243904979982.436, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 
1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 
1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 
1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 1135712080.73169, 
1135712080.73169, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 
43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 
43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 
43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 43757981186.1123, 
84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 
84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 
84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 
84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 84627071382.8667, 229303056718.835, 
229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 
229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 
229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 
229303056718.835, 229303056718.835, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 
49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 
49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 
49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 49361300135.532, 
49361300135.532, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 
125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 
125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 
125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 125649196878.251, 
86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 
86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 
86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 
86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 86161108797.036, 179602936079.222, 
179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 
179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 
179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 
179602936079.222, 179602936079.222, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 
94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 
94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 
94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 94404756931.174, 
94404756931.174, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 
133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 
133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 
133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 133518994859.842, 
61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 
61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 
61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 
61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 61903388459.4489, 173239930602.09, 
173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 
173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 
173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 
173239930602.09, 173239930602.09, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 
104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 
104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 
104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 104967688571.511, 
104967688571.511, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 
60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 
60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 
60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 60587833493.8126, 
77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 
77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 
77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 
77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106, 77833148430.7106), IMR = c(1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 
1016, 1016, 1016, 1016, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1018, 
1018, 1018, 1018, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 
855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 855, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 
1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 
1081.9, 1081.9, 1081.9, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 
956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 956.4, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 
932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932, 932)), row.names = c(NA, 
300L), class = "data.frame")```
````